# Want to show fourth tab panel of tabcontainer as default

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, gridview

I Want to show fourth tab panel of tab container as default when redirected from one page to another page, Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex = 3
     ' ...
```

Comment: The redirecting page is a user control i want to show fourth tab as default for one particular page only not all page..how to send it in querystring?